# How to skip elements in stream up to one matching a condition? (Java)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to skip elements up to "round". I can do this by specifying offset:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of( "gangland", "horror", "hand", "round", "suave", "paradise");
List<String> result = s.skip(3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But in real life I don't know the position of this elemnt. Is there a way to skip everything up to predefined value?